# Yammer Embed Feed using WebBrowser Control

Tags: oauth-2.0, yammer

I am developing an application (.Net Windows Form) and using web browser control to show user data and yammer embedded feed. As a starting point, I am using following script in Web Browser Control.

```
<script> 
    yam.connect.embedFeed({
    container: "#embedded-feed",
    network: "mynetwork.com",
    feedType: "group",
    feedId: "11111"});
</script>
```

It shows me “Login with Yammer” sign-in button but it doesn't show embedded feed once I login-in using OAuth dialog. Also OAuth popup is not closed. I tried same html page in browser / IE and it works fine.

How to use embedded feed in client application / web browser control or how to interact with OAuth in this case?

Comment: Are you seeing any exceptions from the popup dialog? Embed uses a popup window. I haven't used the Web Browser control in a while, but it wouldn't surprise me if you needed some code to handle that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth popup callback to the original post via postMessage to let it know that users is authenticated.  And main Embed reload itself.  I am not familiar with Web Browser control.  Your best bet is to look for any error being spitted out.  Or find out if Web Browser control has some limitation around postMessage.